in sumologic how to conditionally aggregate more than one field
In sumologic, I have two logging statements of following nature
2024-04-01 - level:INFO - event_type:APIRequestStart - endpoint:someproject/v1?param=x
...
...
...
2024-04-01 - level:INFO - event_type:APIRequestEnd - time_taken:2 - endpoint:someproject/v1?param=x

So basically, when the api request starts it adds the field event_type:APIRequestStart and when the api request finishes processing, it adds the fields event_type:APIRequestEnd and time_taken:2 (time spent in processing).
I want to calculate, number of statements with APIRequestStart, lets call it no_of_api_calls, number of statements with APIRequestEnd, lets call it successful_api_calls and I want to calculate the average of time_taken.
Essentially I want to create a table like this:



endpoint
no_of_api_calls
successful_api_calls
success_ratio
avg_response_time




endpoint/v1
20
20
1
0.2



I am able to calculate all these three fields separately, but unable to combine them in a single query. For example
_source=logs
| parse "* - event_type:* - *" as rest1, event_type, rest2
| if(event_type="APIRequestStart, 1, 0) as success 
| if(event_type="APIRequestEnd", 1, 0) as handled
| sum(success) as no_of_api_calls, sum(handled) as successful_api_calls

Is it possible to calculate all three fields in single query, so that I can create a table view? Appreciate your time and help.

The query you have pasted looks like a near solution.
Parse
Just this line:
| parse "* - event_type:* - *"

seem incomplete.
Try:
| parse "* - event_type:* - *" as irrelevant1, event_type, irrelevant2

Without the addition, the | parse operator will fail to run.
Also you wouldn't have the "handle" on what is parsed out from the log lines.
Disclaimer: I happen to be employed by Sumo Logic at the moment.

Thanks for the suggestion, but the issue I am facing over is in the log line, there is an additional field that may or may not be present. It's present if the log line contains the word APIRequestEnd othrewise it's not. I want to aggregate that field and create a table shown in the question.
